# How should I include the code files for my AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, structure

Suppose I have a medium-sized AngularJS application with a directory structure similiar to the following:

```
/app
----app.js
----index.html

----/functionalityA
--------/views
------------pageA.html
--------/controllers
------------ctrlA.js
------------ctrlB.js
--------/directives
------------directiveA.js
--------/services
------------serviceA.js
------------serviceB.js

----/functionalityB
--------/views
------------pageB.html
--------/controllers
------------ctrlC.js
------------ctrlD.js
--------/directives
------------directiveB.js
--------/services
------------serviceC.js
------------serviceD.js
```

It has many files. How should I include all of them in my application?

One approach would be to use `<script>` tags for all of them in `index.html`:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityA/controllers/ctrlA.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityA/controllers/ctrlB.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityA/directives/directiveA.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityA/services/serviceA.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityA/services/serviceB.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityB/controllers/ctrlC.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityB/controllers/ctrlD.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityB/directives/directiveB.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityB/services/serviceC.js"></script>
<script src="functionalityB/services/serviceD.js"></script>
```

Is this an acceptable approach?

If not, what other approaches can I take?

Please note, that my question is about understanding the preferred approach of including the project `.js` files. I'm not asking about how to structure my files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - you should classify your files by their function - not by the type.

---

You need to include your JS files one way or the other if you need their functionalty. Maybe you can include them only when they are needed.

You can use a library like [Requre JS](http://requirejs.org/) for this.

Or you can include these script tags in your dynamic views and refer to JQuery in your header to include them dynamically. You can use `ng-include` for this.

The good news is that these scripts can contain controllers and directives if you put them in a way you register them in the module on the fly.

```
myApp.config(function($controllerProvider, $provide) {
    myApp.controlProvider = $controllerProvider;
    myApp.serviceProvider = $provide;
});

myApp.serviceProvider.factory('myDynFactory', function(){
        return {
                  //Whatever you like
        }
});

myApp.controlProvider.register('myDynController', [function($scope) {

   //Whatever you like
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't incorrect to include all those files in separate script tags, but they will each create a separate request to the server. This is not very efficient, since each request will have its own headers and other bloat. However, if the server and the browser both support HTTP/2, this would not be a problem.

But since HTTP/2 is still new and not widely supported, the source files are usually bundled together into one file, or lazily loaded on demand.